# .htaccess simple URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this as my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

The above rewrites `domain.com/page/` or `domain.com/page` to `domain.com/page.php`

It works really well but for file management on server it would be more convenient to be access the `/folder/index.php` files from `/folder/` or `/folder` URL instead of looking for `/folder.php`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Only now I realized that the rules break my php file uploader. I call it using ajax. The file upload progress in ajax and everything seems fine until the file is uploaded and the uploadHandler.php returns an error because it can't find `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` Do you know how I could fix this? Should I share more of my code?

Comment: Sorry, did research and found the answer [here](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php). Changed the ajax request from uploadHandler.php to uploadHandler/. Not the best practice but it works.